# Fluent-FFMPEG : Is it possible to apply a volume filter only after a specific time has passed

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I have the following code :

```
ffmpeg()
.addInput(videoFilepath)
.addInput(soundTrackFilepath)
.inputOptions("-stream_loop -1")
.outputOptions("-shortest")
.complexFilter([
    {
        filter: "volume",
        options: ["0.15"],
        inputs: "1",
    }
])
```

What i want is for this filter to only be applied let's say after 4s. Is it possible ?

Comment: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Timeline-editing

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов So i've added the following line to my filter:
```enable: "gte(t, 4.2)"```
But it applies the filter to the whole audio instead of after 4.2s have passed.
What did i do wrong ?

Comment: it is option for volume. maybe, that way `options: ["0.15", "enable=...` idk

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов It was indeed that. Thank you. Last question : Is it possible to do something like ```"enable= between(t, 2, 4) or between(t, 5, 7) or ..."``` ? Meaning that the filter applies to all of those time intervals.

Comment: just use + `enable='between(t,1.17,3.62)+between(t,4.12,4.42)+gt(t,12)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Баяр Гончикжапов mentioned.
The correct way to apply the filter options was `["volume from 0 to 1", "enable=between(t, start_time, end_time)"]`

To apply the filter to multiple sections just use `+`